# How can I download the English model using digital ink?

Tags: android, google-mlkit

I know how to download the English model according to [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/digital-ink-recognition/android#download_a_new_model) but is it possible to download the file and put it in the project because some users in my app may have not the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not officially supported by ML Kit at the moment.

We will consider raising the priority if seeing more developers requesting it.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I always see your comments in other posts talking about this library, You always say, Waiting of seeing more developers requesting a specific feature to add it. Please don't wait for any developer to add a new feature. Just improve this library with your team and after developers see the magic in this library will use it. Please take care of it.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your feedback. However, no matter how large the team is, the engineer resource always has a limit. It will be very hard for us to take every single feature request and work on them right away. Unfortunately we have to do some prioritization. Hope you understand and thanks for your support and interest in ML Kit.